# Which pronoun (you or yourself) is correct in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

Which one is correct (or better)?

- Take an umbrella with **you**.
- Take an umbrella with **yourself**.

Answer (score 3):

**Yourself** is a reflexive pronoun, but it is not being used reflexively in your example.

So your first example is grammatically correct.